# Showing that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} k\mathbb{E}(X^k g(X)) = 2a$, where $a = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} g(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Given a continuously differentiable $g$, $a = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} g(x)$ exists, and a random variable $X$ on $[0,1]$ such that the pdf of $X$, $f(x) = 2x$, on $0\leq x \leq 1$. Furthermore, $\mathbb{E}|g(X)| < \infty$.

Show that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} k \mathbb{E}(X^k g(X)) = 2a$.

Here's my attempt. First, we rewrite the above expectation using Taylor expansion,
$$
k \mathbb{E}(X^k g(X)) = k \mathbb{E}\left(X^k \left( g(1) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty g^i(1) \frac{(X-1)^i}{i!} \right)\right) = k \mathbb{E}\left(X^k a + X^k \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty g^i(1) \frac{(X-1)^i}{i!} \right)\right).
$$

Then,
$$
k\mathbb{E}(X^ka) = ak\mathbb{E}(X^k) = ak \int_0^12x^{k+1}\,dx = 2a \frac{k}{k+2} \rightarrow 2a,
$$
as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

However, I am having trouble dealing with the remaining terms of the expansion. If I can show that the expectation of the remaining terms is $0$, then I am done.

Would appreciate guidance on this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

We have to show that $\int_0^{1}kx^{k}g(x) (2x) dx \to 2a$. This is equivalent to $\int_0^{1}kx^{k+1} [g(x)-a] x dx \to 0$. Now $\int_0^{1-\epsilon}kx^{k+1} [g(x)-a] x dx  \leq k(1-\epsilon)^{k+1} \int_0^{1} [g(x)-a] x dx$ which tends to $0$ (for fixed $\epsilon$) by boundedness of $g$. Finally, $\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}kx^{k+1} [g(x)-a] x dx <\eta$ if we choose $\epsilon$ such that $1-\epsilon <x<1$ implies $|g(x)-a| <\eta$. [Note that $\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}kx^{k+1}  dx=\frac k {k+2}<1$].